# Nginx + PHP-FPM produce 502 bad gateway instead of fatal error?

Tags: php, nginx, php-fpm, xdebug, symfony

I'm currently testing Symfony2 with Nginx and PHP-FPM. I also use Xdebug.

Symfony2 comes with a Demo bundle, I wanted to test the new handling of fatal errors which comes with Symfony 2.2.0 by creating a syntax error in the Acme/Demo bundle. Why I do that, the server response is 502 bad gateway.

But if I make a syntax error in the file app_dev.php (so before the framework is fired), then Xdebug tells me about the fatal error.

And surprisingly, if I fix that typo, then re-create the syntax error in the Acme/Demo bundle, then Symfony error handler appears as expected. And finally if a fix all typos (page works) then again re-create that same typo (again in Acme/Bundle), I get a bad gateway.

Do you have any clue on this?

Comment: Any update? I have the same issue

Comment: Here also for updates

Comment: What line appears in your nginx error.log when you get the bad gateway error? This is 90% a wrong pointing to a PHP-FPM socket. Also, can you show us your nginx configuration and the PHP-FPM pool config you use?

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me yesterday.It was an error handing off from nginx to php5-fpm turned out that the php-fpm service was configured to listen on the wrong socket.

in /etc/php5/php-fpm.conf I changed to:

listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock

and in all of /etc/nginx/
make sure fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock

HTH

Comment: Nope, my configuration works since I can use the app. It's only on this specific scenario, I described.

Comment: Try changing the buffers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27173945/homestead-502-bad-gateway-instead-of-whoops-for-php-errors

Answer (score 0):

You could track the exact issue by checking the nginx logs.

```
/var/log/nginx/sitename.error.log
```

502 is because there is some issue in connecting to the php-fpm process. Log can give you more details. If you want to isolate the log, mention seperate error_log under the location of your php application, like

```
    location <name> {

    error_log /var/log/nginx/site_location.error.log;
  #  error_log /var/log/nginx/site_location.error.log debug;

    }
```

(if nginx is trying to connect to different port/ phpfpm/socket you could get answer from this)